# React-Native dynamic "this"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I had do some searching, can't find any related sample, maybe my search keyword is not correct.

I doing a OTP component, I do some research and successfully set dynamic state  for each OTP input, however I wish to call the `focus()` method when input is field up, I would like to do it dynamically for **less and clean code**, code bellow this.[`otpinput_${from + 1}`].focus(); is not correct.

```
onFocusChangeText = (value,from) =>{
    let newState = {};
    newState[`otpinput_${from}`] = value;
    this.setState(newState,()=>{
      this.[`otpinput_${from + 1}`].focus(); // issue here
    });
}

<TextInput ref={(r) => this.otpinput_1 = r} style={styles.otpitem} keyboardType="number-pad" onChangeText={(text)=> this.onFocusChangeText(text,1)} />
<TextInput ref={(r) => this.otpinput_2 = r} style={styles.otpitem} keyboardType="number-pad" onChangeText={(text)=> this.onFocusChangeText(text,2)} />
<TextInput ref={(r) => this.otpinput_3 = r} style={styles.otpitem} keyboardType="number-pad" onChangeText={(text)=> this.onFocusChangeText(text,3)} />
<TextInput ref={(r) => this.otpinput_4 = r} style={styles.otpitem} keyboardType="number-pad" onChangeText={(text)=> this.onFocusChangeText(text,4)} />
<TextInput ref={(r) => this.otpinput_5 = r} style={styles.otpitem} keyboardType="number-pad" onChangeText={(text)=> this.onFocusChangeText(text,5)} />
<TextInput ref={(r) => this.otpinput_6 = r} style={styles.otpitem} keyboardType="number-pad" />
```

Comment: I am confused. When you type in input you want that input get focus? It is default and it will get focus automatically right?

Comment: @ravibagul91 the next input focus, because it is OTP

Comment: You should have some condition to focus next input right? Condition like input text length=6, correct?

Comment: What is the condition to focus next input?

Comment: @ravibagul91 not sure do you read my code or not, i mark down this.[`otpinput_${from + 1}`].focus(); will be focus the next input automatically when setstate is done

Comment: Check my answer and let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer my own question, hope help other ppl:

- create a array
- put each ref a array index

`this.otpinput_ = [];`

```
onFocusChangeText = (value,from) =>{
    let newState = {};
    newState[`otpinput_${from}`] = value;
    this.setState(newState,()=>{
      this.otpinput_[from + 1].focus(); // fixed
    });
}

<TextInput ref={(r) => this.otpinput_[1] = r} style={styles.otpitem} keyboardType="number-pad" onChangeText={(text)=> this.onFocusChangeText(text,1)} />
<TextInput ref={(r) => this.otpinput_[2] = r} style={styles.otpitem} keyboardType="number-pad" onChangeText={(text)=> this.onFocusChangeText(text,2)} />
<TextInput ref={(r) => this.otpinput_[3] = r} style={styles.otpitem} keyboardType="number-pad" onChangeText={(text)=> this.onFocusChangeText(text,3)} />
<TextInput ref={(r) => this.otpinput_[4] = r} style={styles.otpitem} keyboardType="number-pad" onChangeText={(text)=> this.onFocusChangeText(text,4)} />
<TextInput ref={(r) => this.otpinput_[5] = r} style={styles.otpitem} keyboardType="number-pad" onChangeText={(text)=> this.onFocusChangeText(text,5)} />
<TextInput ref={(r) => this.otpinput_[6] = r} style={styles.otpitem} keyboardType="number-pad" />
```

That it, no need extra library

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing only number as argument,

```
onChangeText={(text)=> this.onFocusChangeText(text,1)}
```

You need to directly pass `ref` of next input as argument,

```
<TextInput ref={(r) => this.otpinput_1 = r} style={styles.otpitem} keyboardType="number-pad" onChangeText={(text)=> this.onFocusChangeText(text,1,this.otpinput_2)} />
<TextInput ref={(r) => this.otpinput_2 = r} style={styles.otpitem} keyboardType="number-pad" onChangeText={(text)=> this.onFocusChangeText(text,2,this.otpinput_3)} />


//Do this for all other input.
```

Your function is,

```
onFocusChangeText = (value,from,nextRef) =>{
    let newState = {};
    newState[`otpinput_${from}`] = value;
    this.setState(newState,()=> nextRef && nextRef.focus(); // Now no issue here);
}
```